# Elif error, and no Output

Tags: python

Write a Python function that will test a function.

When the Old Gents Club members get together for a party, they like to smoke cigars. A Gents Party is successful when the number of cigars is between 40 and 60, inclusive. Unless it is a weekend, in which case there is no upper bund on the number of cigars. Return True if the party with the given values is successful, or False otherwise.

Party(30, False) → False
Party(50, False) → True
Party(70, True) → True

Your program should test the function in these ways and produce the correct output:

Party(30, False) → False 
Party(50, False) → True 
Party(70, True) → True 
Party(30, True) → False 
Party(50, True) → True 
Party(60, False) → True 
Party(61, False) → False 
Party(40, False) → True 
Party(39, False) → False 
Party(40, True) → True 
Party(39, True) → False

```
def Party(Cigars, IsWeekend):
    us = bool(True)
    if IsWeekend == False:
        if Cigars < 40:
            us = bool(False)
            elif IsWeekend == True:
                if Cigars < 60:
                    us = bool(False)
                if Cigars > 60:
                    us = bool(False)
                    print(us)
Party(30, False)      
Party(50, False)      
Party(70, True)        
Party(30, True)       
Party(50, True)       
Party(60, False)       
Party(61, False)        
Party(40, False)        
Party(39, False)        
Party(40, True)        
Party(39, True)
```

The "elif" is giving an error, but as far as I can tell this is correct syntax... I need extra eyes.. any suggestions?

Comment: Please format your code. Formatting is critical in Python, and without proper formatting it's impossible to tell where your error might be.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Oops, I just suggested a formatting edit

Comment: No, my code looks exactly how it looks on here... I just didnt format it to properly for this site. But its all the same.

Comment: Then your answer is in the formatting: It's not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elif` should have a matching `if` which is not the case in your code.

Ex:

```
if something:
    # <do_something>
elif something else:
    # <do_something_else>
```

In the above example the elif has a matching if.

In your code

```
elif IsWeekend == True:
```

has no matching `if` block.

You probably intend to do this:

```
def Party(Cigars, IsWeekend):
    us = bool(True)
    if IsWeekend == False:
        if Cigars < 40:
            us = bool(False)
    elif IsWeekend == True:
        if Cigars < 60:
            us = bool(False)
        if Cigars > 60:
            us = bool(False)
    print(us)
```

Just as a note (unrelated to the problem at hand), a few suggestions:

- In python when you are comparing something to be `True`, you can just
  do a `if condition` instead of `if condition == True`. Same goes with
  checking for False. You can just do `if not condition` where ever you
  wanna do a `if condition == False`.
- Also as @Henry Kieter pointed out, you need not do a `bool(True)` or
  `bool(False)`. Just use `True` or `False` directly.

Comment: Another thing worth noting: `bool(True)` and `bool(False)` are superfluous at best. Just use the `True` and `False` singletons directly.

Comment: @user3444456 Could you please accept the answer if it helped resolve your issue? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I just changed the place you `print us`. Make a note of it as well.